# Laravel Error when Using Value from $Request

Tags: laravel, forms

I have the following form, this is a simple form with only a single radio button:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
        <h1>Accomodation</h1>
        <p>This is the accomodation page.</p>

    {!! Form::open(['action' => ['UserController@update', Auth::id()], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
            <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::label('ConsiderForAccommodation', 'Consider Me For Accommodation')}}
                    {{Form::checkbox('ConsiderForAccommodation', 'Consider Me For Accommodation', false)}}
            </div>
            {!! Form::token() !!}
            {{Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT')}}
            {{Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
@endsection
```

I am then trying to update the value "ConsiderForAccomodation" which is a field I added to the users table:

```
 /**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request)
{
    // Update the given user
    $user = auth()->user();

    $user->ConsiderForAccommodation = $request->input('ConsiderForAccommodation');

    $user->save();

    return redirect('/accommodation');
}
```

However, upon checking the box and then submitting the form, I am given this error:

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'Consider Me For Accommodation' for column 'ConsiderForAccommodation' at row 1 (SQL: update `users` set `updated_at` = 2019-03-18 20:44:37, `ConsiderForAccommodation` = Consider Me For Accommodation where `id` = 1)
```

It seems to be reaching this update method, however, I seem to be doing something wrong as it's not picking up the value of the checkbox.

What am I doing wrong? If more of the code is required I'll be happy to update the post.

EDIT - User table migration, looking in MySQL the column has been created as a "TinyInt" which as far as I know is the correct type:

```
class UserAddAccomodationFields extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    // Add field "ConsiderForAccommodation" to table.
    Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->boolean('ConsiderForAccommodation');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    // Remove field "ConsiderForAccommodation" from table.
    Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->dropColumn('ConsiderForAccommodation');
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Could you add your migration(s) for the table?

Comment: I'm not sure what the signature for `Form::checkbox` is, but it looks like it's setting the value of `$request->input("ConsiderForAccommodation")` to `Consider me for Accommodation`

Comment: @rpm192 Added :)

Comment: @TimLewis - Aye, I noticed that too, however looking through my example projects and such, the implemented way should be bringing across the value of the checkbox not the label.

Comment: Should yes, but quite clearly isn't, as `$request->input("ConsiderForAccommodation");` shows that it contains literally that string. Check your source code; (right click your checkbox and inspect element), you'll probably see `<input type="checkbox" name="ConsiderForAccommodation" value="Consider Me For Accommodation"/>` (or similar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `laravelcollective/html` documentation I see the following.

```
Form::checkbox('name', 'value', true);
```

Which means that you should change your checkbox code to this:

```
{{Form::checkbox('ConsiderForAccommodation', 1, false)}}
```

I'm assuming that the value gets passed in the request when the checkbox is ticked and that it returns `null` otherwise, not entirely sure though.

Assuming the above, you can do something like this in your controller:

```
if($request->input('ConsiderForAccomodation') == null) {
   $user->ConsiderForAccomodation = 0;
} else {
   $user->ConsiderForAccomodation = 1;
   // or $user->ConsiderForAccomodation = $request->input('ConsiderForAccomodation');
}
```

Comment: Was just about to post that I got it working by testing the returned value for NULL and also recoding the checkbox element on the view. Thank you for posting this :)

Comment: No problem! Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have error in your Sql Table Structure.

```
`SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'Consider Me For Accommodation' for column 'ConsiderForAccommodation' at row 1 (SQL: update `users` set `updated_at` = 2019-03-18 20:44:37, `ConsiderForAccommodation` = Consider Me For Accommodation where `id` = 1)
```

`

This Means That `ConsiderForAccommodation` Column is Datetime Format.
You are trying to Write an Integer in it.

Please Look at Migrations Or Sql Table And Update it if you want to use it as `boolean` or `Integer`

Comment: I've included the migration for the user table in my post, the field is being created as a boolean (in MySQL it's also appearing as a TinyInt which should be correct).

Comment: Check your checkbox value in source Then check value of it in request. `dd($request->all())`